# facebook login manager throws Error: Login Failed

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Using the code sample from their github page -

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
      (result) => {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          console.log("Login cancelled");
        } else {
          console.log(
            "Login success with permissions: " +
              result.grantedPermissions.toString()
          );
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
      }
    );
```

This runs perfectly fine on android but does nothing in ios. I tried `LoginManager.logOut()` without success.
I have double checked my `info.plist` details. Can't seem to figure out why login fails.

Comment: Same happening with me

Comment: @CassianoMontanari I got around it by downgrading all facebook related pods to `4.38.0`. Specifically `FacebookSDK`, `FBSDKShareKit`, `FBSDKCoreKit` and `FBSDKLoginKit`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually not using CocoaPods, using SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest `4.39` version seems to be buggy. I got around it by downgrading all facebook related pods to `4.38.0`.

My pod file looks like this -

```
  pod 'FacebookSDK', '~> 4.38.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.38.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the 
setLoginBehavior(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'browser : 'native_with_fallback');

It will create the webView if there will be no facebook app installed in your phone for android.