# React native fbsdk showing login failed without any Facebook popup

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

I am new in react native I need to implement Facebook login so I follow Facebook steps which is in below screenshot:

[image]

After that added below line in my pod file and run pod install

```
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

After that I get some code for info.plist and I paste them.

After that I added some code in AppDelegate.m:

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

After setup I copied this function and calling onPress:

```
_fbAuth() {

   LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
     function(result) {
       if (result.isCancelled) {
         console.log("Login cancelled");
       } else {
         console.log(
           "Login success with permissions: " +
             result.grantedPermissions.toString()
         );
       }
     },
     function(error) {
       console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
     }
    );
 }
```

When I click on button every time getting below error:

```
Error: Login Failed
    at createErrorFromErrorData (NativeModules.js:146)
    at NativeModules.js:95
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (MessageQueue.js:397)
    at MessageQueue.js:127
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:297)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:126)
    at debuggerWorker.js:72
```

Please anyone can help me into this that will appreciable....Thanks!

Comment: You might already be logged in, try logging out first `LoginManager.logout()`

Comment: Yes I tried this already.

Comment: I am getting this same error. My app used to work fine with FB login, and now all of a sudden it does not - same exact error as you. Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: I was able to fix my error using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/53754900/5792155